# Adding quotes to the array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, backslash

I have an array of strings. I need to add slashes to the array of values dynamically. How can I do this in JavaScript?

**Input:**

```
["opera","admatic"]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
["\"opera\"","\"admatic\""]
```

Comment: You need to add \ or \"

Comment: You seem to be adding *escaped quotes*, not backslashes. To what end? Did you try anything? What happened?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried with replace regex but i didnt worked

Comment: can you add your regex? then we can help you

Comment: Well you're adding not replacing, so it's unclear why you took that route, but please give a [mre].

Comment: It really would help if you explained why [you think you need to do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Answer (score 2):

You've said you need to add "backslashes", but you don't. You just need to add quotes. In a string literal delimited with double quotes (`"example"`), you use a backslash in front of a double quote in order to have the quote in the string (instead of having it end the string literal), like this: `"here's a quote: \" that was it."`. But there is no backslash in the **string**, just in the string literal in the code to write it. Alternatively, you can use a string quoted with single quotes, in which you have to escape single quotes, not double quotes: `'here\'s a quote: " that was it.'` So we want to add quotes at the beginning and end of those array entries.

To modify all of the entries in an array, typically you use the `map` method to create a new array with the modified values in it, like this:

```js
const original = ["opera","admatic"];
const updated = original.map(str => '"' + str + '"');

console.log("original:", original);
console.log("updated:", updated);
```

You could also use a template literal (delimited with backticks) to build the new string instead of string concatenation:

```
const updated = original.map(str => `"${str}"`);
```

```js
const original = ["opera","admatic"];
const updated = original.map(str => `"${str}"`);

console.log("original:", original);
console.log("updated:", updated);
```

Answer (score -1):

you need double back slashes

```
const oldArray = ["opera","admatic"];
const newArray = oldArray.map(item => '\\"'+item+'\\"');
```